# Chrome Extension change url in the same popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension, and in it i need to open a new link for the Spotify web API authorisation. However, window.open() opens it in a new tab and my extension popup closes. Is there a way to open an url over the default_popup or at least keep it from closing automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Use chrome.identity API [Chrome Extension OAUTH with Spotify API](//stackoverflow.com/a/38305120)

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to w0xx0m i got it to work. Turns out, i needed to use the [Chrome  identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`.

In my case, i tried to authorize with Spotify on behalf of the user, and get the return url which contained the access token.

```
     chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        url : THE_AUTHORIZATION_URL,
       //If interactive is set to false, the logon screen won't show up
        interactive : true},

        function(data){
            //the 'data' contains the return URL
            .......
        });
   });`
```